# Is a square a $\Delta$-complex?

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

*Notation and definitions:*

- *$\Delta^n$ is the standard $n$-simplex with **ordered** vertices $[v_0,\ldots,v_n]$;*
- *$[v_0,\ldots,\hat{v_i},\ldots,v_n]$, where the hat denotes omission, is a face of $\Delta^n$ and is an $(n-1)$-simplex, and this restriction **respects the ordering**;*
- *$\mathrm{int}\Delta^n$ is $\Delta^n$ minus the union of all its faces.*

The definition of a $\Delta$-complex, a generalisation of a simplicial complex, from Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology* is as follows:

> Let $X$ be a space.
> A $\Delta$-complex structure on $X$ is given by a collection of continuous maps
> $$\{\sigma_\alpha\colon\Delta^n\to X \mid \alpha\in A\}$$
> such that
>
> 1. The restriction $\sigma_\alpha\mid_{\mathrm{int}{\Delta^n}}$ is injective, and each point in $X$ is in the image of exactly one such restriction;
> 2. each restriction of $\sigma_\alpha$ to some face of $\Delta^n$ is one of the maps $\sigma_\beta\colon\Delta^{n-1}\to X$ (identifying the face of $\Delta^n$ with some $\Delta^{n-1}$ by the canonical linear homomorphism **respecting the ordering of the vertices**);
> 3. $A\subset X$ is open if and only if $\sigma_\alpha^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\Delta^n$ for each $\sigma_\alpha$.

My question is, why is the following space $X$ only a $\Delta$-complex when we include the orange $1$-simplex?
[image: square]
Note that there are no $2$-simplices in the above picture, and the arrows represent the ordering of the vertices, and not side identification.

I feel like the clue is in the name: a square is most certainly not a triangle (at least, not to my knowledge), and so it makes sense that it wouldn't merit the honour of being a $\Delta$-complex.
I'm sure this is something obvious, but really can't quite spot what exactly...

**Bonus question:** what are these $\Delta$-complexes called? That is, if I were doing a literature search for more information, what would I search for?

Comment: Surely $\{ V_0, V_1, V_2 \}$ is an example of a $2$-simplex in the picture?

Comment: @GuyPaterson-Jones can't we imagine this as a 'hollow' space? That is, just a graph?

Comment: Answer to Bonus Question: $\Delta$-complexes is what they are called. This book is the best literature regarding them.

Comment: To answer your main question, if you insist that your space $X$ is the union of the four blue edges, then obviously those four blue edges define a $\Delta$-complex structure on $X$, and obviously the yellow edge is not in $X$ and so addition of that yellow edge does not define a $\Delta$-complex structure on $X$. Could your confusion arise from mis-interpreting somebody's example, in which the intention was that the interior of the square **is** part of the space $X$?

Comment: @LeeMosher That's possible. I was simply wondering whether or not $\Delta$-complexes had to be made from 'triangles'. So if we just have a square (the blue lines in the above) then this has the structure of a $\Delta$-complex, but if we 'fill in' the square with a $2$-simplex then we require the yellow line and two $2$-simplices to give it a $\Delta$-complex structure?

Comment: 2-dimensional $\Delta$-complexes are defined using solely vertices ($0$-simplices), edges ($1$-simplices), and triangles ($2$-simplices). So if your subdivision includes a square which is **not** subdivided into two $2$-simplices then that is **not** a $\Delta$-complex. It is, on the other hand, a CW complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a short answer to my question: yes, a square (with no $2$-simplices) as in the picture does have the structure of a $\Delta$-complex.
Though if we 'fill it in' with a $2$-simplex, we actually need to use two, and also add in the $1$-simplex that is represented by the orange line in the picture.